# How to change page content based on user input?

Tags: javascript, html

[Conceptually speaking]
What I've done so far:
A user will type in a word: let's say "dog." After clicking the "submit" button, the page will pop out a table of dog pictures and information about each dog.

What I am hoping to do:
If the user decides to search for another animal, let's say "cat", I want my dog pictures to be all removed and basically start from fresh again.

Is this something that can be done in a few lines? This is not part of my project assignment but I did notice when testing my site that I can only search once. After that, I think it calls on everything again and seems to create more columns (but you don't see them because not enough space).

I'm thinking if I can check if my div class="results-playlist" is empty, then somehow I can use .empty() or .remove() to start over again.

Here is a snippet (it doesn't work because it's only to show sorta an outline of my code)

```js
$(document).ready(
 if ($())
 // Query the soundcloud API when clicking the search button
 $('#searchButton').on('click', function() {
  var input = $('#input').val();
  $('#input').val('');
  callAPI(input);
  $('.results-playlist').append(
   '<div class="column" id="resultsContainer"><h2>Search Results</h2><div id="results-list"></div></div><div class="column" id="playlistContainer"><h2>My Playlist</h2><div id="play-list"></div></div>');
 }));
```

```html
<head>
  <title>HW 04 Advanced Javascrip and JQuery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img id="main-logo" src="assets/soundcloud.png">
  </header>

  <section class="search">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Search for a song or artist">
    <button id="searchButton">Search</button>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="results-playlist">
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src=“http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js“></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="startercode_HW4_skeleton.js"> </script>
<script type=“text/javascript” src=“http://stratus.sc/stratus.js“></script>
```

Sorry if this question is asking in an unconventional way! I'm basically interested in learning how search engines can renew the search based on every new user input and model a very basic version of that here if it's relatively simple. Thank you!

Comment: You can use replace() to replace the elements of the page everytime a new search query inserted. Match the query with database and refresh the page on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, just use `.empty()`.

```
$('#searchButton').on('click', function() {
    var input = $('#input').val();
    $('#input').val('');
    callAPI(input);
    $('.results-playlist').empty().append(
        '<div class="column" id="resultsContainer"><h2>Search Results</h2><div id="results-list"></div></div><div class="column" id="playlistContainer"><h2>My Playlist</h2><div id="play-list"></div></div>');
}));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!